# How to limit the download speed of APT?

Tags: apt

I am downloading a very large package and my internet connection isn't the fastest, so browsing the web at the same time is a pain. How can I limit the bandwidth `apt-get` uses?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

A trick I picked up when adjusting someone else's computer:

- For temporary limits, add the `-o` flag to your `apt-get` command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::Dl-Limit=25 install <package>
  ```
- For permanent throttling, create the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/75lowerspeed` and save the following in it:

  ```
  Acquire
  {
     Queue-mode "access";
     http
     {
        Dl-Limit "25";
     };
  };
  ```

Both methods limits `apt-get` to 25 kBps (kilobytes per second).

- You can also use a traffic shaping program, such as [wondershaper](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wondershaper) [image: Install wondershaper] or [trickle](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trickle) [image: Install trickle].

Comment: I was writing about `wondershaper`, but your answer is better.

Comment: so finally I beat YOU for once :-D

Comment: @Rinzwind - I don't know how you keep coming up with these answers, but please keep doing so!

Comment: @boehj just well homed searching skillz if I may say so myself ;)

Comment: Well, I'm digging ur skillz my man. Keep it up!

Comment: Wow This is so useful! I'd give this +10 If I could :)

Comment: The person that gave me the 18th upvote here got me over 20k rep. Thanks! :D

Comment: So useful when you don't want to disturb others doing there work on-line :)