# Why can't I browse internet while downloading torrent or updates?

Tags: bittorrent

I've recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu since I was windows 7 made my laptop very slow.

I thought updating Ubuntu before I start using it properly would be the best option, but when I start updating, I cannot browse the internet anymore.

The same happens when I'm downloading a torrent or installing an application from Ubuntu s
Software Center.

Is there any way to fix this? I experienced same issue in Linux Mint 15 as well.
Haven't had this issue in Windows though.

Can somebody help me understand why it happens in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is because downloading torrents/packages uses all of your download bandwidth. You can try to investigate this by limiting the download/upload speed in yout bittorrent client. In the Transmission client you can find this in the menus via Edit -> Preferences -> Speed.

See the answer to [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50402/limiting-the-download-rate-of-apt-get) for information on how to throttle the bandwidth usage of `apt`, the package manangement software.

Comment: will try that :)

Comment: And, did it work out?

Answer (score 0):

In most of the times it is not Operating System's error, it is the torrent client that saturates your connection.

I have faced many times this problem on Linux machines and with various clients Transmission, Deluge, etc.

The solution is to optimize your client according to your connection. There is a guide I always follow when I setup a new system.

Check the following, they are from the same website:

- [Optimizing Transmission](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/optimizing-transmission-bittorrent-client-speed.htm)
- [Optimizing μTorrent](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/optimizing-torrent-speed.htm)
- [Optimizing Deluge](http://www.techsupportalert.com/optimizing-deluge-speed)

I take it that your internet connection is not very fast and this causes problems not only with Torrent clients but while apt is running for updates/upgrades and installs. If this is the case you can check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/50405/12218) on how to throtle apt-get download speed.

Comment: i will but it's not only torrents that I face the issue with. same happens when i'm installing ubuntu updates as well. how do I limit that. Other systems cannot browse internet as well