# Limit bandwidth usage of "do-release-upgrade -d"

Tags: server, upgrade, do-release-upgrade, bandwidth

I'd like to upgrade a 15.10 server to 16.04 LTS beta* using `do-release-upgrade -d`. This is a ~2GB download and I'd like to limit the bandwidth usage of the upgrade. This is possible by setting "Acquire" in `apt.conf` (?) for `apt-get`, but will this also apply to `do-release-upgrade`? How would I implement it?

*I'm aware that I am upgrading a server to a beta version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I placed the following, slightly modified from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/50405/9081) answer, into `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and then ran `do-release-upgrade -d`.

```
Acquire
{
   Queue-mode "access";
   http
   {
      Dl-Limit "50";
   };
};
```

The upgrade proceeded at ~50Kb/s.

Comment: To avoid permanent change to the configuration under `/etc/` I have created local copy of `/etc/apt/apt.conf` with your change applied and then ran `sudo APT_CONFIG=/home/wojtek/do-release-upgrade/apt.conf do-release-upgrade`